# action="." always submits the form to the same page in all versions of HTML?

Tags: html, forms, url, action

I have always used forms in that way, but recently I tried to do the same in another project and when I submit it goes to another page (directly to the root url of the site) so I'm wondering if there is some special situations in any of the versions of html or xhtml where the assumption that actions="." submits the form to the same page doesn't holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `action` attribute so it submits the form to itself...the same page

Note, that in HTML5 this is the same where the `action` attribute is not required

Comment: So I should avoid to use action="." from now right?

Comment: `.` usually is similar to adding `./` to an anchor...so, if you want to submit the form to the same page you should either leave the `action` attribute empty or explicit specify the name of the page...`action="current_page.html"`

Comment: HTML5 doesn't require the action attribute, but if you add the action attribute you can't leave it empty (it doesn't validate).

Comment: @OMA Thanks for pointing that out. You're 100% correct, I just edited the answer to reflect that

Comment: Please also note that in the previous version, HTML 4, the exact opposite was true, actually: The action attribute was required, but you could leave it blank with an empty string (action=""), so it depends on what DocType you're using (as far as validation is concerned). The browsers won't care either way.